# How to add directory bookmark when the parent directory is not readable?

Tags: permissions, nautilus, filesystem, directory, bookmarks

In file dialogs and file managers, it's possible to add bookmarks
representing directories, used similar to other "places".

To add a bookmark for a directory, I have to enter the parent directory and use the context menu of the subdirectory of that parent that I'm interested in.

How to add directory bookmark when the parent directory does not have the execution or search permission `x` for me, so it's is not readable? Not readable means it  is not possible to list the entries, one of which is the one I want to bookmark. I can still traverse the directory to a readable subdirectory, if all directories above have `x` permission and I know the name before.

What would be needed is a function where the bookmarked directory name is entered manually, as it fundamentally can not be listed, no way around.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>, enter the address to the desired directory, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>.

Comment: When I tried, it did not work where I tested - Thunderbirds add attachment dialog, KDEs [Wait, I mean the DE formerly known as KDE] Dolphin, and Gnomes Files

Comment: @VolkerSiegel Wait, your parent directory doesn't have the `x` permission or the `r` permission? Without `x`, you can't reach any subdirectory. And did you go directly to the directory you want to bookmark? I tested it just now and worked fine on GNOME Files, and I'd bet it would work on any other which used these shortcuts (which are pretty common).

Comment: I'll add my example - it's `/tmp/user/1000/` - I see I confused the permissions `x` and `r` - what I do not have on the parent directory is `r` actually.

Comment: Yes, I can enter the full path - but then, Im' inside the directory I want to bookemark.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel then you press Ctrl-D and the current directory will get bookmarked.

Comment: To make sure we use the same - do you use a specific dialog to try?

Comment: @VolkerSiegel no, just the GNOME Files program. Ctrl-D doesn't show any dialog.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24020/discussion-between-muru-and-volker-siegel).